# objective c id *

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pointers

I am using the KVO validations in my cocoa app. I have a method

```
- (BOOL)validateName:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError
```

My controls can now have their bindings validate. How do I invoke that method with a `id *` NOT `id`

To use the value that is passed in (a pointer to a string pointer) I call this:

```
NSString * newName = (NSString *)*ioValue;
if ([newName length] < 4) {
```

otherwise i get bad exec crashes...

passing in with type casting doesnt work: `(id *)myStringVar`

passing in with a regular id doesnt work either :  `(id) myStringVar`

Comment: `id` itself is already a pointer type. Objects can be freely cast from and to `id`, but not to `id*`. If this doesn't work, then it's a problem in your algorithm somewhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSError *error;
[self validateName:&myStringVar error:&error];
```

The ampersand means "address of." In this case, it is the address of the pointer, or in other words, a pointer to a pointer (which is what an `id*` is).

Comment: More precisely, `&myStringVar` is a pointer to the `myStringVar` variable—that is, the address of the `myStringVar` variable. The variable holds an `id`, so the type of the pointer to the variable is a pointer to `id`—in other words, `id *`.